# Neo4j parallelRuntimeSupport "DISABLED" not valid error

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm trying to run neo4j on locaL. But I'm getting this error. Could you help me?

```
2023-04-16 21:22:55.250+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on localhost:7474.
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.options.InvalidCypherOption: DISABLED is not a valid option for parallelRuntimeSupport. Valid options are: disabled, all
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.options.CypherOptionCompanion.invalidValueError(CypherOption.scala:146) ~[neo4j-cypher-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]



I have tried to find "parallelRuntimeSupport" variabe in config files but I can't find anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version 5.8.0 fixed this error for me.

Comment: Do you know why? Can you provide a reference to the version notes?